# In AnimateCC, when I add a button from the library it doesn't work and instead runs through all of the states continuously

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I'm currently using html5 Canvas. When I add an instance of my button to the stage it works perfectly fine. But when I add it programatically to the stage, it's almost like it acts like an animation. It just runs through the up, over and down states repeatably. Anyone know a fix?

Here's the code I use to add the button:

var myButton = new lib.MyButton();

this.addChild(myButton);

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I fixed the issue. I simply placed the button inside a movieclip and then added that movieclip instead.